# Create column based on dictionary of words

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a set of words that correspond to a number, example:

```
word1, word2, word3 = 1
word4 = 2
word5, word6 = 3
word7, word8, word9 = 4
word10 = 5
```

I want to create a dataframe where there is 2 columns, one with every single word and another with the correspondent number, example:

```
 Word   Number
------- -------
 word1    1
 word2    1
 word3    1
 word4    2
 word5    3
 word6    3
 word7    4
 word8    4
 word9    4
 word10   5
```

How can I create a dictionary and use it to create the column Number in function of the Word key and the respective value

Comment: What kind of input do you have? A dictionary? If so, please provide it and be more specific

Comment: does the number of "wordX" variables varies too  ?

Comment: where is the dictionary you are talking about? and what did you tried so far?

Comment: I wanted to create something like this:
my_dict = { 
                  1: ['word1', 'word2', word3'],
                  2: ['word4'],
                  3: ['word5', 'word6],
                  4: ['word7', 'word8', word9'],
                  5: ['word10]
                 }

Where I check in wich list the word is and extract the number.

Answer (score 0):

This might be over doing it since the question doesn't seem clear enough, but here is a possible way of doing it :

- Assuming you have variables with names that start with 'word'.
- And what you want is to create a dict out of them to pass to the DataFrame method.
- And assuming you'll be running this py file as a script so that `__name__=='__main__'`.

Here is the Code example :

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

word1 = word2 = word3 = 1
word4 = 2
word5 = word6 = 3
word7 = word8 = word9 = 4
word10 = 5

main_module = sys.modules['__main__']

words = [
    v_name for v_name in main_module.__dict__ if v_name.startswith('word')]
# ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6', 'word7', 'word8', 'word9', 'word10']

numbers = [getattr(main_module, v_name) for v_name in words]
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]

# Creating the Dict
d = {'Word': words, 'Number': numbers}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
#     Word  Number
#0   word1       1
#1   word2       1
#2   word3       1
#3   word4       2
#4   word5       3
#5   word6       3
#6   word7       4
#7   word8       4
#8   word9       4
#9  word10       5
```